# Find documents by geodistance filter on geoshape field of type Point in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I have my documents in elastic search containing locations. They contain a field in the documents called `location` with the mapping: `"location": {"type": "geo_shape"}`. I have cities and countries indexed in the document.

In city type documents, (identified by a field `"location_type": "city"`), the location field looks like this: `"location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [12.343, 43.454]}`.

In country type documents, (identified by a field `"location_type": "country"`) , the location field looks like this: `"location": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[12.343, 43.454], [12.23, 34.231]...]}`.
My question is, can i run the geo_distance filter query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "location_type": {
            "value": "city"
          }
        }
      }, 
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": 100,
          "distance_unit": "km",
          "location.coordinates": {
            "lat": 40.73,
            "lon": -74.1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me an error, saying: nested: QueryParsingException failed to find geo_point field [location.coordinates]

How can i make this query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this approach. Writing it here for others' reference.

```
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "circle",
          "radius": "100km",
          "coordinates": [ 
            86,
            27
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```